# Setting the value of a hidden variable on button click and then Submit the Form using .submit() jquery struts

Tags: html, jquery-ui, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a problem with Form Submit in struts.
Setting the value of a hidden variable on button click and then Submit the Form using `.submit()` jquery is not allowing to show the sucess message in the same page in struts.

when the button is clicked, before the form is submited I need to set a hidden variable from the click of the button and then the form is to be submitted.
I am able to submit the form using the below code but not in the same popup.

```
<div id="formResult" >
  <s:form id="formId" name="form">
    <s:hidden id="actionId" name="action"></s:hidden>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="90%" >
      <s:if test ="approve">
        <tr>
          <td>File is Approved!!</td>
          <td><td>
        </tr>
      </s:if>           
      <s:elseif test ="rejectFile">
        <tr>
          <td>File is Rejected!</td>
          <td><td>
        </tr>
      </s:elseif>           
      <s:else>
        <tr>
          <td width="30%"><b><s:text name="idLabel" /></b></td>
          <td width="40%"><s:property value="Id"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div style="height:5px"></div></td>
          <td><div style="height:5px"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      </s:else>
      <tr>
        <td width="90%" colspan="2" align="right">
          <s:if test="!approveFileSuccess">
            <sj:a 
              id="approvefileId" 
              onclick="approveFunction();"                      
              button="true"
              targets="formResult">
              Approve
            </sj:a>
          </s:if>                       
          <s:if test="!rejectFileSuccess">
            <sj:a 
              id="rejectfileId" 
              onclick="rejectFunction();"               
              targets="formResult" 
              button="true">
              Reject
            </sj:a>
          </s:if>
    </table>
  </s:form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**:

```
function approveFunction(){
  $('#actionId').val("Approve");
  document.formId.submit();
}

function rejectFunction(){
  $('#actionId').val("Reject");
  document.formId.submit();
}
```

When `document.formId.submit();` is clicked form submit takes the popup to another page. Not able to show success in the same page.

Comment: Everytime someone post a totally unindented HTML, somewhere in the world a panda dies.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: LOL. :) Lets save them.

Comment: BTW you have some not closed tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it right for the same code given above with a few changes. Without Ajax it can be done..!! 
Use onClickTopics which does the work before the form is submitted and also without refreshing it :)

JSP

```
<sj:a 
id="approvefileId" 
formIds="approvefileform"                       
button="true"
targets="formResult"
onClickTopics="beforeApprove">
Approve
</sj:a>
```

JQUERY

```
$.subscribe('beforeApprove', function(event,data) { //before form submit on click functionality 
$('#actionApproveRejectId').val("Approve"); //to set the hidden variable
});
```

Its Working Perfect!!!!!!